# Rails: make custom URL helper behave like built in _path & _url helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, helper, urlhelper

I'm having a hard time figuring out the "Rails Way" to add a email confirmation URL to a mailer.

I'm opting not to do this purely RESTfully because, well, it's difficult with text email because they can't `PUT` requests.

so here's my routes.rb: `get 'confirm/:id' => 'Confirmations#confirm'`

and in my mailer I'd like to put `email_confirm_url(@user.email_token)` where I want the URL to occur.

I created a helper:

```
#app/helpers/confirmations_helper.rb
module ConfirmationsHelper
  def email_confirm_url(token)
    "/confirm/#{token}"
  end  
end
```

this all works, sort of, except when I call `email_confirm_url(@user.email_token)`…

I literally get: "`/confirm/abcdefg…`"

When what I want is: `http://myhostname/confirm/abcdefg…`

Or in development: `http://localhost:3000/confirm/abcdefg…`

How can I make my URL helper behave more like the built in `<resource>_path` and `<resource>_url` helpers in Rails? though realistically I suppose I really only *need* `_url`.

**#Edit:** I have this in my environment config:

```
#config/environments/development.rb
...
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a helper to convert my `_path` method into a `_url` method.

Rails uses `ActionDispatch::Http::URL.full_url_for` to produce the `_url` methods, and passes in `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options` to set the `host`, `port`, and `protocol`.

This means you can generate a URL from a given path with

```
ActionDispatch::Http::URL.full_url_for(Rails.application.routes.default_url_options.merge(path: path))
```

My work in progress helper looks like:

```
def self.url_helper(route_name)
  define_method("#{route_name}_url") do |*args|
    path = public_send(:"#{route_name}_path", *args)
    options = Rails.application.routes.default_url_options.merge(path: path)
    ActionDispatch::Http::URL.full_url_for(options)
  end
end
```

This could then be used in combination with your path helper to build an `email_confirm_url` method:

```
url_helper :email_confirm
def email_confirm_path(token)
  "/confirm/#{token}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the request object you should implement this function in the controller for your mailer and pass it to the template with a variable.

app/mailers/emailer.rb

```
@tracking_url = "http://#{request.host}:#{request.port}/confirm/#{token}"
```

app/view/emailer/template_name.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'name', @tracking_url %>
```

Comment: `ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method 'host' for nil:NilClass` I think I remember something about not having access to `host` or `host_with_port` in Mailers?!? Any way around this?

Comment: updated answer based on the above comment, let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

What about using an already existing url plus concatenation? I.e. you can use `root_path` and `root_url`, then you concatenate and the behavior is exactly the same as rails!

For example you can do this:

```
def mystrangemethod_url(option1, option2)
  "#{ root_url }/#{ option1 }/#{ option2 }"
end
```

And you are done. Easy and the only requirement is set **set your root path in routes.rb**.  Also with the option you have set in development.rb, it will work also in mailers too.

Comment: I think the Q is more like how to transparently access `mystrangemethod_url` from a view.